# How to write xpath expression for data-extracting with visibility_of_all_elements_located?

Tags: python, selenium

There is a table whose xpath is `.//table[@id='target']`  in target webpage, I want to get all data in the table (all text in td in the table).
Should i write the wait.until statement

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, ".//table[@id='target']")))
```

or

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, ".//table[@id='target']//td")))
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both commands will NOT give you what you are looking for.
`visibility_of_all_elements_located` will NOT really wait for visibility of ALL the elements on the page matching the passed locator.
`visibility_of_all_elements_located` method actually waits for at least 1 element matching the passed locator to be visible.
So, to make sure all the elements are visible you will have to add some sleep after that command.
Also, I think that waiting for table internal elements visibility should be better than waiting for the table element itself visibility.
So, I would use something like this:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, ".//table[@id='target']//td")))
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: it is no need to use time.sleep.

Comment: wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

Comment: wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, ".//table[@id='target']//td")))

Comment: Well, if you are sure you know Selenium better than me - no problem

Comment: time.sleep can block the main thread for a while.

Answer (score 0):

`tds` are basically **not** `direct child` but `descendant` :

```
.//table[@id='target']/descendant::td
```

should be the right xpath.

```
all_table_data = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, ".//table[@id='target']/descendant::td")))
```

`all_table_data` is a list that contain all the web elements.Print like below and that should give you all the data available in selenium view port.

```
for data in all_table_data:
    print(data.text)
```